# Recreational integral problem: $\int_0^1 (x+\sqrt[3]{x^3-1})^{2018}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics

I have a (recreational) integral problem any interested inhabitants of MSE to enjoy:

> Evaluate the following integral:
>   $$\int_0^1 \bigg(x+\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}\bigg)^{2018}dx$$

I promise, it's not from an ongoing math competition (I just put the $2018$ in there to be funny). If you don't believe me, you can try solving the problem with $1,000,000$ (or any large even number, really) instead of $2018$.

Cheers!

Comment: +1 Why the downvote its tagged as recreationnal mathematics...

Comment: @tired What do you mean? It's defined the way the cube root has always been defined on real numbers...

Comment: @tired I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B(x%5E3-1)%5E(1%2F3),%7Bx,0,1%7D%5D

Comment: @tired How so? Try plugging in $1/2$...

Comment: @tired I don't think so. For every real number $a$, there exists exactly one real number $b$ such that $b^3=a$. We define the cube root of $a$ to be equal to $b$. This should always work out just fine, since the function $f(x)=x^3$ is a bijective function from reals to reals.

Comment: @tired It appears that Wolfram is plotting *complex* cube roots as well. But I'm dealing *only with real numbers.*

Comment: Guess you can't trust WA because that graph is not what Desmos suggest. How could even be positive for $0<x<1$

Comment: @tired wolframalpha differentiate between $x^{1/3}$ and $\sqrt[3]{x}$. The first one is understood as a complex valued function, the second no. Take a look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CubeRoot%5B-1%2F2%5D)

Comment: If you replace $2018$ with $3$, Wolfram Alpha spits out a rather interesting closed form in terms of the gamma function!

Comment: @FrankW. Heh heh, some nasty things happen when the power is odd. But I promise, *my* integral can be done without advanced methods. XD

Comment: sorry to everyone... i need  some sleep

Comment: @tired I guess you're too *tired* to continue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write
$$I = \int_0^1 \bigg(x+\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}\bigg)^{2018}dx.$$
Making the substitution $u^3 + x^3 = 1$, we get
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{u^2}{\sqrt[3]{1-u^3}^2}\bigg(u+\sqrt[3]{u^3-1}\bigg)^{2018}\,du.$$
(The fact that $2018$ is even is important here, as it removes a minus sign inside the parentheses).
Hence
$$2I = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{u^2}{\sqrt[3]{1-u^3}^2}+1\right)\bigg(u+\sqrt[3]{u^3-1}\bigg)^{2018}\,du.$$
But, if $v = u + \sqrt[3]{u^3-1}$ then $\frac{dv}{du} = \frac{u^2}{\sqrt[3]{1-u^3}^2}+1$, which is exactly the left factor.
So,
$$2I = \int_{-1}^1 v^{2018}\,dv=\frac{2}{2019}$$
Hence $I = \frac{1}{2019}$.

Comment: how you get your $2I$? I have that $$\frac{u^2}{\sqrt[3]{1-u^3}^2}+1=\frac{u^2+\sqrt[3]{1-u^3}^2}{\sqrt[3]{1-u^3}^2}\neq \frac{2u^2}{\sqrt[3]{1-u^3}^2}$$

Comment: I added the equations 1 and 2 together: nothing fancy!

Comment: Wow, elegant!$\phantom{}$

Comment: @B.Mehta Nicely done; this is just how I did it! In general, I've discovered this fancy integral trick: if $E$ is an even function, $\theta$ is an involution, and $a$ is a constant, then
$$\int_a^{\theta(a)} E(x-\theta(x))dx=\int_0^{\theta(a)-a}E(x)dx$$